# How do I get the Podio app_id by app name?

Tags: podio

I have the app name and I need to get the app_id for that app. Is there a function in podio that returns the app_id if I provide the app name?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Podio [Search in space v2](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-space-v2-155195763) API call to get the app details using the app name.

You can also use [Search in organization v2](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-organization-v2-155196203) API call to fetch the details.

If you do not know both the `space_id` and the `organisation_id`, then you may use the Podio [Search globally v2](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-globally-v2-155196238) API call in order to get the details of the app.

You may need to pass the app name in the `query` parameter and `ref_type => app`.

Try the sandbox in the mentioned links to know more about the response from the search.